# Terminal taking keyboard input when not supposed to

Tags: python, terminal, pycharm

When I in a for loop in PyCharm it lets you type in stuff.
Is there a setting to turn that off?

Here's my code

```py
while True:
    pass
```

and it shows

[image: screenshot of terminal in IDE]

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This only happens if you use a [run configuration](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/run-debug-configuration-python.html) (in other words by clicking one of the green run buttons). It doesn't happen if you run the script directly using the terminal in the OS or by running the script using the [Terminal Emulator](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/terminal-emulator.html).

This can be disabled by going to `Run` `>` `Edit Configurations` and checking `Emulate terminal in output console`. As shown in the screenshot.

[image]